# What is the expected lifetime of lpszClassName in WNDCLASS(EX)?

Tags: c++, winapi

When creating a `WNDCLASS(EX)` in C++, one might do as follows:

```cpp
WNDCLASSEX wndClass {};
wndClass.lpszClassName = "MyWndClass";
```

The data backed by the string literal is available for the whole program's lifetime.

So what if the data was only available during the invocation of `RegisterClassEx`?

```cpp
{
  char className[] = "MyWndClass";

  WNDCLASSEX wndClass {};
  wndClass.lpszClassName = className;
  // other things...

  RegisterClassEx(&wndClass);
}

HWND window = CreateWindowEx(0, "MyWndClass", /* other parameters... */);
```

Would this still work?

Comment: Given: _"...The data backed by the string literal is available for the whole program's lifetime..."_ I am not sure what your question is ?

Comment: @RichardCritten I think the question is: What happens if the code is using an array with a limited life-time, for example defined locally inside another function which registers the window-class?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude possibly, but what would be nice is a [mcve] to illustrate the question so who ever attempts to answer it can be sure.

Comment: The `WNDCLASSEX` itself doesn't care how long the strings are valid. The entity that cares is the function that *uses* the `WNDCLASSEX`. In general, parameters passed to a function need to be valid only until the function call returns.

Comment: Edited for clarity.

Comment: I'd think it's copied anyway. it's unlikely you change a char in `className` and the actually window class name also changes.

Comment: `RegisterClassEx` returns a handle to allocated ATOM wrapping class name. So class name string is copied into the table of atoms and can be later retrieved from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So what if the data was only available during the invocation of RegisterClassEx? Would this still work?

Yes, it is perfectly fine. The *values* that you register are copied by the OS until the class is unregistered at a later time. The actual `WNDCLASSEX` instance itself is no longer needed once `RegisterClassEx()` returns.

So, what is important is that the class name *value* that you register must match the class name *value* that you pass to `CreateWindowEx()`. They do not need to be pointing at the same *memory address*.